# How to post RDF data with appropriate Content-type header using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, content-type, rdf

With XMLHttpRequest (on Firefox!) I try to post RDF data in turtle or N3 format to a service, but this seems not to be possible. Whenever I issue setRequestHeader( 'Content-type',  .....) with either 'application/turtle' or 'text/n3', the post does not reach the service and returns status 0.

May it be that this object is definitely restricted to post 'text/plain' or 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' data only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only uses GET or POST.  If POST is used to send data to the server, the Content-Type of the data sent to the server with the HTTP POST request is one of **application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain**.

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control